# Debian 10 - Background image isn't being displayed

Tags: linux, debian, amd-graphics, wallpaper

Hello everyone I recently installed Debian 10 on my computer, everything was fine until I realized the background image wasn't being displayed instead I'm seeing a solid grey color as background, I tried using an image on a different location but the issue persists.

I had to manually install the ADM drivers following the steps on this [**guide**](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo) since screen resolution was really small. What am I missing and how could I fix this issue? thanks to all.

[image: Background]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the drivers, if your GPU is GCN 1.1 or older this will work for you.

1. You have to uninstall `xserver-xorg-video-all` packages with `apt remove *xserver-xorg-video*`
2. use `lspci -nn | grep VGA` to check what GPU you do have. You will get an output like this:

01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. **[AMD/ATI] RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]** [1002:9710]

3. Go to [Debian repositories](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=search) and search the name of your GPU using "description" filter. You will find one of these 3 packages on the results;`xserver-xorg-video-mach64`, `xserver-xorg-video-r128` or `xserver-xorg-video-radeon`.
4. Now install the proper xserver-xorg-video package that matches your GPU. I.e `apt install xserver-xorg-video-radeon`